# Is a polynomial of degree 3 with irrational roots possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

It is easy to give an example of a polynomial of degree 3 with *integer coefficients* having:

(a) three distinct rational roots,

(b) one rational root and two irrational roots.

But for a while I am trying to construct one that all its roots are irrational but I can't. It seems that it is not possible at all?

Also, can a polynomial with *integer coefficients* of degree 3 have two rational roots and one irrational root?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR, two rationals one irrational, is my question

Comment: Note:  I assume you are requiring that all roots are real.  Otherwise $x^3-2$ does the job.

Comment: @Edi with rational coefficients?

Comment: If the polynomial has integer coefficients, then the sum of the roots is rational.  Therefore, it cannot have one irrational and two rational roots.

Comment: @taritgoswami, integer coefficients; and root must be real if they are irrational

Comment: There isn't a clear, universally accepted, convention on "irrational $\implies$ real".  Some people say all non-real complex numbers are irrational. See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823970/is-i-irrational) 
 Always worth specifying your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Take $p(x)=x^3-3x+1$, for instance. By the rational root theorem, it has no rational root.

Comment: When there are two questions, and you say "it" is possible, we do not know which one you mean.  A reason to limit questions to one only.

Comment: @GEdgar: that's quite right. Of course, you can infer which case is targeted here.

Comment: @GEdgar When I posted my answer, there was only one question.

Comment: Adding my 2nd question was almost simultaneous with your answer! :)

Answer (score 11):

By Vieta the sum of the roots must be rational, hence this excludes a single irrational.

All other cases are possible.

$$\begin{align}0&:x(x^2-1)=0,
\\2&:x(x^2-2)=0,
\\3&:8x^3-6x-1=0.\end{align}$$

---

The last one was built from

$$\cos3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta=\cos\frac\pi3$$

so that the roots are

$$\cos\frac\pi9, \cos\frac{7\pi}9, \cos\frac{13\pi}9.$$

Comment: Sure it is, the roots of that are 0, sqrt(2), and -sqrt(2). The two irrational roots are sqrt(2) and -sqrt(2).

Answer (score 2):

To the first one of your queries the answer is - No, it's not possible to construct if you want all coefficients to be rational. As, from Vieta's formula we have sum of roots of a polynomial $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ equals to $-b/a$, which is rational as you want all $a,b,c,d$ to be integers.

Now,if you want one root to be irrational, you can't get the sum a rational one. As, you will always need the conjugate surd(conjugate of $a+\sqrt{b}$ is $a-\sqrt{b}$, which is irrational) to make the sum a rational one. For any other non-algebraic irrational number like $e$, no matter what you take, you will get the product a irrational number, but from Vieta again product of roots is $-d/a$, a rational number.

For the case with all 3 irrational roots, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1717575/579780).

Comment: See José's answer for three irrational roots with sum $0$ and product $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any second order polynomial with two irrational roots (shouldn't be hard) $q$, and take $$p(x) = (x-1)\cdot q(x)$$

then, clearly, $p$ has one rational root (it's $1$) and two irrational roots (the same as $q$)

---

However, it is **not** possible for the polynomial $p$ to have two rational roots $r_1, r_2$ and one irrational one $z$. That would imply that $p=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-z)$, and clearly, the expanding this polynomial shows that the coefficient at $x^2$ is $-z-r_1-r_2$. This number is rational only if $z$ is also rational.

Comment: two rationals one irrational, is my question

Comment: This case is already known by the OP.

Comment: Note $0$ is rational.  So it is better to use the $x^2$ coefficient.

Comment: @GEdgar You are correct, I fixed it.